# Abort bash script, if a certain console output string appears

Tags: bash

I'm using a bash script to automatically run a simulation program. This program periodically prints the current status of the simulation in the console, like "Iteration step 42 ended normally".

Is it possible to abort the script, if the console output is something like "warning: parameter xyz outside range of validity"? 
And what can I do, if the console output is piped to a text file?

Sorry if this sounds stupid, I'm new to this :-)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can ask better-quality questions by posting sample code and sample output.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an ideal job for Bash. However, you can certainly capture and test STDOUT inside a Bash iteration loop using an admixture of conditionals, grep-like tools, and command substitution.

On the other hand, if Bash isn't doing the looping (e.g. it's just waiting for an external command to finish) then you need to use something like [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect#External_links). Expect is purpose-built to monitor output streams for regular expressions, and perform branching based on expression matches.